# How to delete the file that was sent as StreamContent of HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse, dispose

In ASP.NET webapi, I send a temporary file to client. I open a stream to read the file and use the StreamContent on the HttpResponseMessage. Once the client receives the file, I want to delete this temporary file (without any other call from the client) 
Once the client recieves the file, the Dispose method of HttpResponseMessage is called & the stream is also disposed. Now, I want to delete the temporary file as well, at this point.

One way to do it is to derive a class from HttpResponseMessage class, override the Dispose method, delete this file & call the base class's dispose method. (I haven't tried it yet, so don't know if this works for sure)

I want to know if there is any better way to achieve this.

Comment: The above approach seems to work, but the Content needs to be disposed before the file is deleted (as the stream to the file is still open) `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Content.Dispose();
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(_localFile);
            file.Delete();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288749/how-to-delete-the-file-that-was-sent-as-streamcontent-of-httpresponsemessage#comment21586235_15288749) helped solve the question... I wrote about it here:

[Delete temporary file sent through a StreamContent in ASP.NET Web API HttpResponseMessage](http://www.leniel.net/2013/10/delete-temporary-file-sent-through-streamcontent-aspnet-webapi-httpresponsemessage.html)

Here's what worked for me. Note that the order of the calls inside `Dispose` differs from your comment:

```
public class FileHttpResponseMessage : HttpResponseMessage
{
    private string filePath;

    public FileHttpResponseMessage(string filePath)
    {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        Content.Dispose();

        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add, the same question has been asked a month after this answer, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137283/web-api-how-to-detect-when-a-response-has-finished-being-sent), and it's similar to this one. But instead of subclassing `HttpResponseMessage`, it do so with `StreamContent`. I feel more comfortable doing the job in that way as it is closer to the problem in question (overriding less behavior), avoiding the explicit call to `Content.Dispose();`

Comment: Be very careful with approaches like this. The `Dispose(bool)` method is meant to be called from both `Dispose()` and from finalizers. And finalizers must NEVER throw. So you would probably want to test `disposing`, and only call `File.Delete` if `disposing` is true.

Answer (score 16):

Create your StreamContent from a FileStream having DeleteOnClose option.

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StreamContent(
        new FileStream("myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, 
              FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose)
    )
};
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I did it by reading the file into a byte[] first, deleting the file, then returning the response:

```
        // Read the file into a byte[] so we can delete it before responding
        byte[] bytes;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        }
        File.Delete(path);

        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        result.Content.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.bar");
        return result;
```

Comment: Hope your files aren't too big.